# Passing objects to html from Blaze Template helpers

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars

I am looking for a way to be able to pass an object from `Template.templateName.helpers` to the html.

It seems that the syntax: `{{objname.property}}` does not work in spacebars.

How do I do it ?

Comment: Could you show your helper and HTML?

Comment: That should absolutely work if `objname` is actually an object (and not `undefined`)